# Fedora 31 Grub2 configuration change isn't being applied

Tags: fedora, grub, grub2, fedora-31

I've changed `GRUB_TIMEOUT=-1` in my `/etc/default/grub` because I want the grub boot loader to wait forever for me to choose my operating system.

Most of the internet says to run `update-grub` after editing this but it seems like this is a one-line file, not present on Fedora 31, that simply runs `grub2-mkconfig >/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` .  After making a backup of my old `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` I run that command and reboot.

I still have the old 5-second count-down.

Running strace shows `grub2-mkconfig` is indeed reading `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` .

Checking the output shows `set timeout=-1` several places in the output file, so I would assume the edit has taken control, and this was `5` in the original file.

I've spent an hour googling this and it's amazing how little traction I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output location in the `grub2-mkconfig` command in the question is for BIOS systems.  If you have a directory called `/sys/firmware/efi` you instead have an UEFI system and must instead run

```
grub2-mkconfig >/etc/grub2-efi.cfg
```

Doing that, and rebooting, causes my edit to take effect.

`/etc/grub2-efi.cfg` is a link on my Fedora 31 system to `../boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg` .

Comment: congrats on not giving up on googling :)